# Enviorment Texture cannot be seen on object

Tags: texturing, glass

I try to make a Moebius Strip on combination of colored glass. I Used a tutorial to fake the glass effect, but the effect does not work. It only works on the cube ( at least it did yesterday) I can not replicate the issue. I can not figure out what the Problem is. See screenshots. I used the following video for the colored glass effect. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhrj5CO6yfs

[image: Nodes For Mobius Strip]

[image: As a group]

[image]

[image: The coloful texture should be visible, but it is all white.]

[image]

Comment: First of all, your environment texture called "daniel-olah..." is not using an _Environment Texture_ node. It is an _Image Texture_ node set to _Flat_ projection which will not be displayed correctly in the viewport. You have to use an _Environment Texture_ and use _Equirectangular_ projection (it should be set to this by default). In the last screenshot there is an _Environment Texture_ node - but the background is set to _Transparent_, so of course you cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the glass material works on your cube and not on the moebius is because you **disconnected the Geometry Nodes' Geometry Input**:
[image]

So, all materials that were assigned to the original object also got disconnected.

Here is a cube with dummy material and a geometry node setup with the input geometry connected; material is intact:
[image: GeoNode Material]

And here's the same Object with disconnected Geometry Input (similar to what you did, but with a simple cube primitive); material is gone.

[image]

To fix this , you can insert a **Set Material Node**; Material is back.

[image]

Comment: Although you might be correct about the missing glass material, the question also has one screenshot where there is marked in red that the background does not seem to represent what is expected to be seen. And that has nothing to do with a missing glass material. Actually in a purely mostly homogenous greyish environment the glass material wouldn't look much different. And the difference pointed out in the world shader nodetree between the Möbius band and the cube is there and it will result in a seemingly incorrect background image - independent from the glass material.